# Youtube's browser-based upload with SSL in Firefox issue

Tags: youtube-api

We have a browser-based upload form, using the client login authentication. Everything works fine in IE, Chrome, and used to work fine in FF till version 18. Our site uses HTTPS, and we are forced to use SSL connection for the YouTube connection as well. 
The strange thing is that upload works in FF when using HTTP connection, but, unfortunately, we cannot use it. With HTTPS connection we get the token and the upload url without any issues, but when we do the POST – it just hangs at 0b and nothing happens. Checking in the Net tab we can see that the request is in the waiting stage – there is never a response.
How can we find out what is going on there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is linked to https and SPDY.
In Firefox 24, disabling SPDY seems to avoid the issue

- Go to About:config
- search for *network.http.spdy.enabled*
- disable the 3 versions

The bug has been reported to:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4919